# Android Studio throws "duplicate entry: META-INF/rxjava.properties" despite workarounds

Tags: android

everyone.

I'm having this rather nasty error when trying to compile an app in Android Studio 3.5.2, which as the title sugests, is the common "duplicate entry: META-INF/rxjava.properties" error, which is supposedly fixed by adding the following into the Gradle config:

```
packagingOptions {
       exclude 'META-INF/rxjava.properties'
}
```

However, I've been looking around possible solutions, and none of them work. Despite the exclusion being made in the packagingOptions block, Android Studio still halts with the same error.

I'm really stumped here, because nothing seems to work: the aforementioned exclusion, invalidating caches, etc.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried to clean and rebuild the project, or have you tried to delete the ‘build’ folder and building the project again?

Comment: The `exclude` DSL method probably doesn't cause build task invalidation, so when you added it, the packaging wasn't redone. Doing a clean build *without build cache* should resolve this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've had exactly the same error since last friday.

```
Execution failed for task ':app:javaPreCompileDebug'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform artifact 'dji-sdk.aar (com.dji:dji-sdk:4.11)' to match attributes {artifactType=android-classes, org.gradle.usage=java-api}.
      > Execution failed for AarToClassTransform: C:\Users\hartmann\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\ebc59111a03cabe9a39a5013ae496f9d\jetified-dji-sdk-4.11.aar.
         > duplicate entry: META-INF/rxjava.properties
```

The `exclude 'META-INF/rxjava.properties'` was already present in my build.gradle file before the error occurred.

Invalidating cache, disabling build cache, deleting build files etc. all do not work.

What actually fixed the issue for now was changing the gradle version from 3.5.2 back to 3.5.1 in the projects (the one at the top level) `build.gradle` file:

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.1'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

UPDATE 06.JAN 2020:

After updating the Android Version on the smartphone and a Gradle update to 3.5.3 the error didn't reappear.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it?

```
packagingOptions {
    pickFirst 'META-INF/rxjava.properties'
}
```